# Input values are undefined when posting them to views via ajax

Tags: django, jquery

when I post data from value of inputs in form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"{% url DrHub.views.ajxTest %}",
             data: {
                    start: $('#id_startTime').val(),
                    end: $('#id_endTime').val()
             },
             success: function(data){
                 alert(data);
                 console.log('Success!');
                 <!--$("#return").append(data);
             },
             error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert('error!'+thrownError);
            }
    });
</script>
```

in `views.py` :

```
def ajxTest(request):
   if request.is_ajax():
      if request.method == 'POST':
     return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'message' : request.POST.get('start',False)}), mimetype='application/javascript')
   else:
      return render_to_response('DrHub/doctors/nutrition/test.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

it alerts data as undefined
but when I do this:

```
$.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url:"{% url DrHub.views.ajxTest %}",
         data: {
                start: '8',
                end: '10'
         },
```

...

it alerts data (8)

what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

I guess $('#id_startTime') has a undefined value. The $.ajax will execute directly once it's loaded. So you have to wait for some event (for example submitting a form) before executing the ajax thing.

Comment: I submit the form and input with id_start id is in this form!

Comment: Does id_start has an initial value?

Comment: I've checked it with initial value,it is undefiended yet,but when I enclose my ajax code into document.ready it picks the value just when it's an initial value!